# Ref only gets the last element - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get all the elements that has a "ref" attribute in it but failed. It only gets the last element that has a ref attribute, in this case the div with the "lastako" class. Is there a way to get them all as an array of elements? Thanks for the help.

Here's my code

```
<template>
    <section id="news">
        <div id="newscontainer">
            <div class="latestevent pt-4">
                <h1 class="latestnews">LATEST NEWS AND EVENTS</h1>
                <span class="float-right readall">Read all news</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('bell.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">BELL Blue Day</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('family.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">Family Day</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated lastako" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('flores.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">Q Flores de Mayo</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

And on my script tag

```
export default {
        methods: {
            getimgurl(url){
                return require('../../assets/images/frontpage/'+url);
            }
        }, mounted(){
            let vm = this;
            this.$nextTick(function (){
                bus.$on('newsanimation',function (){
                    console.log(vm.$refs.newsanimate);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the referenced elements? People are giving you answers but, I'm curious why you made this decision. Maybe there's another way to accomplish the same thing without using references.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set those tags a same `ref` name, you should place them into a `v-for` in order to make Vue store them in form of array.

In addition, if you want to distinguish them in that array. You can use `:ref=""` instead of `ref=""` for e.g. `<div :ref="'newsanimate'+i" v-for="i in [1, 2, 3]" :key="i"></div>`

So as a result, if you really want to get what you want. Just add `v-for="i in [0]" :key="i"` to the parent `<div>`. For e.g.

```
<template>
    <section id="news">
        <div id="newscontainer" v-for="i in [0]" :key="i">
            <div class="latestevent pt-4">
                <h1 class="latestnews">LATEST NEWS AND EVENTS</h1>
                <span class="float-right readall">Read all news</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('bell.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">BELL Blue Day</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('family.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">Family Day</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="ako animated lastako" ref="newsanimate" :style="'background-image: url('+getimgurl('flores.jpg')+')'">
                    <div class="akodesc">
                        <p><a href="#">Q Flores de Mayo</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting previous refs if you use it that way. If you want your `newsanimate` ref to be an array then use a `v-for` with `ref="newsanimate"` like in this example:

```
<div v-for="i in 3" :class="`test${i}`" ref="newsanimate">{{i}}</div>
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/342633/

Answer (score 0):

According to Vue.js documentation:

> When used on elements/components with `v-for`, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

so, in your case, since you are not defining divs using `v-for`, all the previous references are overwritten by the next ones.

See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) for further references.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe irrelevant. But it is quite important that you need set the :key="" to get the correct ref.

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <Item :key="index" ... ref>
     <button ref... >
```